# Yesterday we went to the park and there were we had a picnic there

Tags: sentence-construction

Are sentences both correct? Is the first sentence often used by native speakers?

> Yesterday we went to the park and there were we had a picnic there.
>
> Yesterday we went to the park and had a picnic there.

Comment: What do you mean by “there were”?

Comment: it's the rule "there is/are..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not correct, no. A native speaker would probably just say

> Yesterday we went to the park and had a picnic.

The picnic taking place in the park is more or less implied, though if you really wanted to be specific you could say

> Yesterday we went to the park and had a picnic there.

The "there were" part of your original sentence is confusing and doesn't make sense. It would normally be used for describing something that was there, but not an action you took (like the picnic). Something like

> Yesterday we went to the park and had a picnic. There were cakes and sandwiches for everyone.